# Performance issues with skeletal animation vertex shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I'm having issues with my skeletal animation vertex shader. When animating about 32 models at once I can only get 60 fps, and on low end computers I get even less. Vertex shader below:

```
uniform mat4 boneMatrixes[128];

void main(){

  vec4 a = gl_Vertex;

  // Apply bone transformation
  a = boneMatrixes[int(gl_Normal.x)] * gl_Vertex;

  gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * a;
  gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;

}
```

Parameters are bound like this (please note that this is Java, I am using the LWJGL OpenGL binding:)

```
int boneMatrixesName = ARBShaderObjects.glGetUniformLocationARB(mProgramShader, "boneMatrixes");

// matrixFloatBuffer is a FloatBuffer of size 128 * 16
ARBShaderObjects.glUniformMatrix4ARB(boneMatrixesName, false, matrixFloatBuffer);
```

Commenting out the `a = boneMatrixes[int(gl_Normal.x)] * gl_Vertex;`
line increases performance by about 500%. How can I increase performance for this vertex shader? It looks as simple and fast as possible.

Comment: "Commenting out the `...` line increases performance by about 500%." Why does this surprise you? Your shader consists of two matrix multiplies and a copy. It's no surprise that your vertex shader runs faster if take away half of its work. Plus, the compiler can optimize `boneMatrixes` out, so it doesn't have to upload your matrix data. What you need to do is better localize the source of the actual problem. Also, stop using `ARBShaderObjects`. Use the core GLSL functionality.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I have found that if I use a constant in the boneMatrixes reference (i.e. boneMatrixes[0] or boneMatrixes[1] etc...) it speeds up to the same level as if I just commented out the code. Do you know why it does that?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the GPU vendor and model, these 128 4x4 matrices may use as many as 512 uniform components. That is an awful lot, and also a lot of that space is wasted, as the part that's actually useful is 3x4. You may want to check out quaternions as a method of uploading skinning information to the GPU and converting them to matrices in the shader.

Comment: Just out of interest, is sending the bone matrices as uniforms the generally done thing, or is there a way of doing it with a second vertex stream?  I think I read about this somewhere, but I've forgotten the details.. :-(.